# Finding the limit of a function with a singularity in the exponent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

The question I have is to determine the type of singularity at $x=1$ of the function
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}
\end{equation}

which is defined on the set $[0,\infty)-\{0\}$. The given hint is $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{log(x)}{x-1} $ is a derivative.

I'm still not really sure where to start with this since I can't see how to take a limit of $f(x)$ easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take the $\ln$ of both sides of $f(x)=x^{\frac1{1-x}}$, then find the limit as $x\to1$ of both sides of that. This trick is usually helpful whenever you have a function in an exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that continuous functions preserve limits.   So,

$\ln \lim _{x\to 1} f(x)=\lim _{x\to 1}\ln f(x)=\lim _{x\to 1}\ln (x^{\frac 1 {1-x}})=\lim _{x\to 1}\frac 1 {1-x}\ln x=\lim _{x\to 1}\frac {\ln x} {1-x}$.

The latter goes $\frac 0 0$, so we can use L'Hosptials rule, to get

$\ln \lim _{x\to 1}f(x)=\lim _{x\to 1}\frac {-1} x=-1$.

Now, taking $e$ as the base and raising both sides, we get

$e^{\ln \lim _{x\to 1} f(x)}=\lim _{x\to 1}f(x)=e^{-1}$.

This is in general a useful technique, anytime you can't figure out where a function goes to, but you can find out where the log goes to, or where the square root goes to, or any other continuous function, do that then undo it at the end.

Comment: woops, I flipped $x-1$ and $1-x$ in here, silly me.  Fixing

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in (0,1) \cup (1,+\infty)$. You may write
$$
f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=e^{\frac{\ln x}{1-x}}=e^{\frac{-(1-x)+\mathcal{O}((1-x)^2)}{1-x}}=e^{-1}+\mathcal{O}(1-x)
$$ showing that the singularity at $x=1$ is removable. We have use $$\ln (1+u)=u+\mathcal{O}(u^2) $$ for $u$ near $0$.